# Show breakpoint at line number in RichTextFx CodeArea

Tags: javafx, breakpoints, line-numbers, richtextfx

I'm working with [RichTextFx](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX)'s CodeArea to highlight custom mini language code.

Now while executing this code I want to show a small arrow in front of current executed line. I know the specific line number but can't get anything to happen with the line number label.

Since github project claims showing line numbers or breakpoint toggles as a feature this can't be very difficult. But can't get anything to work...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To show any graphic in front of the line, you need to set the "paragraph graphic factory" of the CodeArea. This graphic factory is just a function `int -> Node`: given the line number, it returns a `Node` that will be displayed in front of the line.

Here is a graphic factory that produces a green triangle pointing at the line. It will only be shown when the line is equal to the given integer property `shownLine`.

```
class ArrowFactory implements IntFunction<Node> {
    private final ObservableValue<Integer> shownLine;

    ArrowFactory(ObservableValue<Integer> shownLine) {
        this.shownLine = shownLine;
    }

    @Override
    public Node apply(int lineNumber) {
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        triangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        ObservableValue<Boolean> visible = Val.map(
                shownLine,
                sl -> sl == lineNumber);

        triangle.visibleProperty().bind(visible.conditionOnShowing(t‌​riangle));

        return triangle;
    }
}
```

Each graphic (i.e. little green triangle) you create will be observing the given `shownLine` property to decide whether it should be visible. As lines, and therefore line graphics, come and go, it is important to remove the listener of `shownLine` when the graphic is no longer used. `visible.conditionOnShowing(t‌​riangle)` is a new property that will stop observing the `visible` property (and automatically also the `shownLine` property, thanks to ReactFX's lazy binding semantics) and reset to constant `false` whenever the triangle is not part of a showing window. So we don't cause memory or CPU leaks due to uncleaned listeners.

Here is a complete runnable demo that uses this `ArrowFactory` combined with the `LineNumberFactory` provided by RichTextFX to show both line numbers and a little triangle. This demo uses the CodeArea's current line as the `shownLine` property. You will want to substitute it for a property that contains the current line of execution.

```
import java.util.function.IntFunction;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
import org.reactfx.value.Val;

public class CodeAreaWithLineIndicator extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        CodeArea codeArea = new CodeArea();

        IntFunction<Node> numberFactory = LineNumberFactory.get(codeArea);
        IntFunction<Node> arrowFactory = new ArrowFactory(codeArea.currentParagraphProperty());
        IntFunction<Node> graphicFactory = line -> {
            HBox hbox = new HBox(
                numberFactory.apply(line),
                arrowFactory.apply(line));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            return hbox;
        };
        codeArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(graphicFactory);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(codeArea), 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}

class ArrowFactory implements IntFunction<Node> {
    private final ObservableValue<Integer> shownLine;

    ArrowFactory(ObservableValue<Integer> shownLine) {
        this.shownLine = shownLine;
    }

    @Override
    public Node apply(int lineNumber) {
        Polygon triangle = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 10.0);
        triangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

        ObservableValue<Boolean> visible = Val.map(
                shownLine,
                sl -> sl == lineNumber);

        triangle.visibleProperty().bind(visible.conditionOnShowing(t‌​riangle));

        return triangle;
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: CodeArea with current line indicator]

Comment: I guess it would be easier to understand using Val.conditionOnShowing(Node): `triangle.visibleProperty().bind(visible.conditionOnShowing(triangle));` or did I miss something important?

Comment: You are absolutely right. The only reason is that this answer predates the existence of `conditionOnShowing`. I will update the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Working example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
import org.reactfx.value.Val;

import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class CodeAreaWithLineIndicator extends Application {
    CodeArea codeArea;
    TextField textField;
    public static final IntegerProperty lineValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1) ;
/*    public final int getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }*/
/*    public final void setValue(int value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        codeArea = new CodeArea();
        codeArea.replaceText(0,0,"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        codeArea.setPrefHeight(400);
        IntFunction<Node> numberFactory = LineNumberFactory.get(codeArea);
        IntFunction<Node> arrowFactory = new ManualArrowFactory(lineValue);
        IntFunction<Node> graphicFactory = line -> {
            HBox hbox = new HBox(
                    numberFactory.apply(line),
                    arrowFactory.apply(line));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            return hbox;
        };
        codeArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(graphicFactory);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    lineValue.setValue(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }
            }
        });
        Button button = new Button("MoveIt");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    lineValue.setValue(Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                }
            }
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textField, button, codeArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class ManualArrowFactory implements IntFunction<Node> {

        private final IntegerProperty shownLine;

        public ManualArrowFactory(IntegerProperty shownLine) {
            this.shownLine = shownLine;
        }
        @Override
        public Node apply(int lineNumber) {
            Polygon triangle = new Polygon(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0.0, 10.0);
            triangle.setFill(Color.GREEN);

            ObservableValue<Boolean> visible = Val.map(shownLine, sl -> sl.intValue()-1 == lineNumber);

            triangle.visibleProperty().bind(
                    Val.flatMap(triangle.sceneProperty(), scene -> {
                        return scene != null ? visible : Val.constant(false);
                    }));

            return triangle;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For multiline implementation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.LineNumberFactory;
import org.reactfx.value.Val;

import java.util.function.IntFunction;

public class CodeAreaWithLineIndicator extends Application {
    CodeArea codeArea;
    TextField textField;
    public static final IntegerProperty lineValue = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1) ;
    public static final ObservableList<Integer> olistValue = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public static final ListProperty<Integer> listValue = new SimpleListProperty<Integer>(olistValue);


/*    public final int getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }*/
/*    public final void setValue(int value) {
        this.value.set(value);
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        codeArea = new CodeArea();
        codeArea.replaceText(0,0,"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        codeArea.setPrefHeight(400);
        IntFunction<Node> numberFactory = LineNumberFactory.get(codeArea);
        IntFunction<Node> arrowFactory = new MultiBreakPointFactory(listValue);
        IntFunction<Node> graphicFactory = line -> {
            HBox hbox = new HBox(
                    numberFactory.apply(line),
                    arrowFactory.apply(line));
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

            return hbox;
        };
        codeArea.setParagraphGraphicFactory(graphicFactory);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                int newValue = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
                olistValue.add(newValue);

            }
        });
        Button button = new Button("Clear");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                        olistValue.clear();

            }
        });

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(textField, button, codeArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 600, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class MultiBreakPointFactory implements IntFunction<Node> {

        private final ListProperty<Integer> shownLines;

        public MultiBreakPointFactory(ListProperty<Integer> shownLine) {
            this.shownLines = shownLine;
        }
        @Override
        public Node apply(int lineIndex) {
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
            Circle circle = new Circle(10.0, 10.0, 6.0, Color.RED);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(20,20);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            rectangle.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            rectangle.setOnMouseClicked(me->{
                if (!olistValue.contains(lineIndex+1)){
                    olistValue.add(lineIndex+1);
                }
            });
            stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rectangle, circle);
            circle.setOnMouseClicked(me->{
                int index = olistValue.indexOf(lineIndex+1);
                if (index>-1)
                    olistValue.remove(index);
            });
            circle.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            ObservableValue<Boolean> visible = Val.map(shownLines, sl -> sl.contains(lineIndex+1));

            circle.visibleProperty().bind(
                    Val.flatMap(circle.sceneProperty(), scene -> {
                        return scene != null ? visible : Val.constant(false);
                    }));

            return stackPane;
        }
    }
}
```

Enter a number to textfield and click enter. Now only changing oListValue  will show breakpoint lines on the codearea.
[image]